# solve for reduced from for two regressions

Tags: regression, time-series, self-study, econometrics

I have following two regression models

$$y_i=a_1+b_1x_i+c_1z_i+d_1w_i$$

$$x_i=a_2+b_2y_i+c_2z_i+d_2w_i$$

z and w are exogenous to both errors. And I have endogenity problem.

How can I solve for a reduced form model in terms of coefficients of the two models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the two equation and solve for $$y_i= \frac{a_1+b_1(a_2+c_2z_i+d_2w_i+ u_2)+c_1z_i+d_1w_i  + u_1}{1 - b_1b_2}.$$

You can continue to group terms until you get something linear in your exogenous variables and errors.

Then you can get $x$ since you have $y$. I added two error terms since you presumably want them.

Comment: Professor, I know ask too much question, but I try to only understand. These are only framework. I construct all real data and codes by myself. I have one question. (you are really knowledgeable, thank you) what does this question say? please explain what should I do in mathematical expression?(I don't want to solve it or to write code. But I don't understand this question as well. "Justify a set of parameter restrictions that would arguably allow
you to estimate both a supply and a demand curve by instrumental
variables. Be sure to include both exclusion and inclusion type
restrictions."

Comment: I will give you a hint. An exclusion restriction means that the coefficient is zero. If $d_1=c_2=0$, this would let you drop $z$ from the $y$ equation and drop $z$ from the $x$ equation. Inclusion restrictions means the coefficient is not zero (also called relevance). If $c_1 \ne 0$ and $d_2 \ne 0$, you can use $z$ to instrument for $y$ in the $x$ equation and $w$ to instrument for $x$ in the $y$ equation.

Comment: If c2 is zero, z is dropped from x equation as you said. but, if d1 is zero, then w is dropped from y equation. That's, not z is dropped from y equation. Instead of d1=0, c1 should be zero? Is there any mistake?

Comment: by the way, you are excellent. I want to let you know that I added you on Linkedln. Thank you very much.